# Using spy to mock a full object created in the class which is tested

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have the following structure:

```
class A {

    public A(String p){
        // ...
    }

    public String AMethod(String p){
        // ...
    }

}

class B {
    int method(String param){
        A a = new A(param); int n;
        String s = A.AMethod(param);
        // ... (initializes n, ...)
        return n;
    }
}
```

Now I want to test `method` in class `B` but control the output of `AMethod` when it is called. But since I do not create the object A in the test class of B, I cannot mock it normally - how can I mock object A instead?

**I tried Mockito.spy but it doesn't seem to work:**

```
this.ASpy = spy(new A());

when(ASpy.createSession(any())).then(invocation -> {
    // ... (*)
});
```

(*) still doen't get called... but spy should be the right solution, shouldn't it? My problem is: I never create an object `A` in my test class, only in `method` such an object is created but not in the test class.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this (if possible) would be to modify the code of class B so that object A was injected into the method (passed as a parameter, set as a class field or instantiated with usage of a factory class - the factory would be injected as a field and the factory object could be mocked in the test to return a mocked object A).

If actual code modifications are not possible, you could use [PowerMock's whenNew method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/latest/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew-java.lang.Class-) and return a mocked object in your test.

A side note: if you're using JUnit 5, PowerMock may not be a viable solution - read more [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/929).